# How to get cross tab (group_by) with dplyr to include 0s?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to replicate the output of a the table() function using dplyr.
I've includes a copy of the data I'm working with at the very bottom.

When using table() I get a crosstab that includes 0 for missing crosstabulations.

As you can see the Outcome "Pending" is 0 for the month of "Feb"

```
> table(data$Month, data$Outcome)
     
      Negative Neutral Pending Positive
  Apr       48      12       1       75
  Feb       37       6       0       48
  Jan       49       9       0       44
  Jul       12       7     210       41
  Jun       66      47      35       89
  Mar       90      15       5      116
  May       51       9       4       40
```

I can save this into a workable df to make graphs using

```
> as.data.frame(table(data$Month, data$Outcome))
   Var1     Var2 Freq
1   Apr Negative   48
2   Feb Negative   37
3   Jan Negative   49
4   Jul Negative   12
5   Jun Negative   66
6   Mar Negative   90
7   May Negative   51
8   Apr  Neutral   12
9   Feb  Neutral    6
10  Jan  Neutral    9
11  Jul  Neutral    7
12  Jun  Neutral   47
13  Mar  Neutral   15
14  May  Neutral    9
15  Apr  Pending    1
16  Feb  Pending    0
17  Jan  Pending    0
18  Jul  Pending  210
19  Jun  Pending   35
20  Mar  Pending    5
21  May  Pending    4
22  Apr Positive   75
23  Feb Positive   48
24  Jan Positive   44
25  Jul Positive   41
26  Jun Positive   89
27  Mar Positive  116
28  May Positive   40
```

Now when I try to do this with dplyr, I can't get the 0 to appear.

```
> data %>% 
+   group_by(Month, Outcome) %>% tally() %>% data.frame() 
   Month  Outcome   n
1    Apr Negative  48
2    Apr  Neutral  12
3    Apr  Pending   1
4    Apr Positive  75
5    Feb Negative  37
6    Feb  Neutral   6
7    Feb Positive  48
8    Jan Negative  49
9    Jan  Neutral   9
10   Jan Positive  44
11   Jul Negative  12
12   Jul  Neutral   7
13   Jul  Pending 210
14   Jul Positive  41
15   Jun Negative  66
16   Jun  Neutral  47
17   Jun  Pending  35
18   Jun Positive  89
19   Mar Negative  90
20   Mar  Neutral  15
21   Mar  Pending   5
22   Mar Positive 116
23   May Negative  51
24   May  Neutral   9
25   May  Pending   4
26   May Positive  40
```

My goal is to get the same output as using as.data.frame(table(data$Month, data$Outcome)) using dplyr

Thank you.

DATA

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Month = c("Jun", "Mar", "Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", 
"Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jan", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", 
"Jan", "Jan", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Jul", 
"Apr", "May", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Jun", 
"May", "May", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jun", "May", 
"Jun", "Jun", "May", "Jun", "May", "May", "May", "May", "Jul", 
"Jun", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Mar", "May", 
"May", "Jul", "Jul", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Mar", "Jul", "Mar", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "May", "Jul", "Jan", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Jul", "Mar", "Jun", "Jan", "Jul", "Jan", "Jul", "Mar", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "May", "May", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "May", "Jul", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jan", "Mar", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Mar", "Feb", "Apr", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "May", "Jun", "Apr", "Mar", 
"Mar", "May", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "May", 
"Apr", "Apr", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "May", 
"May", "Jun", "Apr", "May", "May", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "May", 
"May", "May", "May", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Jul", "May", "Jul", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Jul", "Mar", 
"Jan", "Mar", "May", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Mar", "Jul", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Apr", "Apr", "Mar", 
"Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jun", "Apr", "May", "Apr", "Apr", "Mar", 
"Jul", "Mar", "May", "May", "May", "May", "Apr", "Jul", "May", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jun", "Jul", "May", "May", "Jul", "May", "May", 
"Jun", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Feb", "Feb", "May", "Feb", "Apr", "Feb", "Jun", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Jun", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", "Apr", "Feb", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "May", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "May", "Apr", "Apr", "Jul", 
"Mar", "May", "May", "Jul", "Jul", "Apr", "May", "Feb", "May", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jun", "Jul", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Jan", 
"Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Feb", "Jan", "Feb", 
"Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", "Apr", "Jun", "May", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Jun", "Jul", "May", "Jun", "May", "May", 
"Jun", "Jun", "May", "May", "Jun", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jun", "May", "Jun", "Jun", "Mar", 
"Jan", "Jan", "Apr", "Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "May", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Feb", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Jan", "Apr", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Jul", "Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Apr", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Apr", "Jun", "Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Jun", "Mar", "Apr", 
"Jun", "Apr", "Jun", "Apr", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jun", 
"Jul", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Mar", "Jul", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Jan", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Jan", "Mar", "Jan", "Jun", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", 
"Mar", "Jun", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "May", "May", "Jul", "Apr", 
"May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Feb", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Apr", "Feb", "Feb", "Apr", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Feb", "May", "May", "May", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "May", "May", "Apr", "Apr", "May", 
"Apr", "Jul", "Apr", "Apr", "May", "Apr", "May", "May", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Apr", "Feb", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Feb", "Feb", "Jul", 
"Apr", "Jun", "Apr", "Jul", "Apr", "May", "Jul", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Feb", "Apr", "Mar", "Jan", "Apr", "Feb", "Apr", "Feb", 
"Jun", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Jun", "Mar", "Jul", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "May", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", "Feb", "Jul", "Jul", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"May", "May", "May", "Apr", "Jun", "Apr", "Jun", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Apr", "Mar", "May", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Apr", "Jun", "May", "May", "May", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Jun", "May", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "May", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Jan", "Feb", "Apr", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Mar", "May", "Apr", "Mar", "Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Jan", "Apr", "Jan", "Jan", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Apr", "Jun", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Apr", "Jun", "Apr", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Mar", "Jun", "Jun", "Mar", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jan", "Jan", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Jun", "Jan", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Jun", "Jun", "Mar", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Jun", "Jan", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Mar", "Mar", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Mar", "Jun", "Jun", "Jan", "May", "May", 
"Jun", "Jan", "May", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Feb", "Jun", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Jan", 
"Feb", "Feb", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"Jun", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "May", "May", "May", "May", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Mar", "May", "Jan", "Jan", "May", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Apr", "May", "Apr", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "Jan", 
"Jan", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", 
"Mar", "Jun", "Mar", "Mar", "Jan", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun"), Outcome = c("Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Pending", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Pending", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Pending", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Pending", "Positive", "Pending", "Negative", 
"Pending", "Positive", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Pending", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Pending", "Neutral", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", 
"Pending", "Positive", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Pending", 
"Neutral", "Pending", "Neutral", "Pending", "Pending", "Neutral", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", 
"Negative", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Pending", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Neutral", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Positive", "Pending", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Neutral", "Pending", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Pending", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Negative", "Neutral", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Pending", "Positive", "Negative", "Pending", "Positive", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", 
"Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Pending", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Neutral", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Positive", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Neutral", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Pending", "Neutral", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Neutral", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Neutral", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Pending", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Pending", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Pending", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Positive", "Pending", "Positive", "Pending", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Pending", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Pending", "Positive", "Neutral", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Neutral", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Pending", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Neutral", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Pending", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Pending", "Positive", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Pending", "Positive", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Negative", "Pending", "Pending", "Neutral", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Negative", "Neutral", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Pending", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Neutral", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Pending", "Negative", "Neutral", 
"Pending", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Pending", "Neutral", "Pending", 
"Positive", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Pending", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Neutral", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative")), row.names = c(NA, -1166L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using `tidyr::complete`, which would be loaded in along with `dplyr` if you loaded `library(tidyverse)`.

```
data %>% 
  count(Month, Outcome) %>% # shortcut for group_by %>% tally
  tidyr::complete(Month, Outcome, fill = list(n = 0))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 28 x 3
   Month Outcome      n
   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 Apr   Negative    48
 2 Apr   Neutral     12
 3 Apr   Pending      1
 4 Apr   Positive    75
 5 Feb   Negative    37
 6 Feb   Neutral      6
 7 Feb   Pending      0  # <-- added with complete() 
 8 Feb   Positive    48
 9 Jan   Negative    49
10 Jan   Neutral      9
# … with 18 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I thought this would solve a larger problem but unfortunately it didn't. If you have a chance please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838910/how-to-lock-colors-for-missing-categories-and-include-missing-x-axis-values-in

Answer (score 2):

An easier option is to use `tabyl` which returns similar output as `table` and then use  `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to reshape the data from 'wide' to 'long'

```
library(janitor)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tabyl(data, Month, Outcome) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Month, names_to = "Outcome", values_to = "n")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 28 x 3
   Month Outcome      n
   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 Apr   Negative    48
 2 Apr   Neutral     12
 3 Apr   Pending      1
 4 Apr   Positive    75
 5 Feb   Negative    37
 6 Feb   Neutral      6
 7 Feb   Pending      0
 8 Feb   Positive    48
 9 Jan   Negative    49
10 Jan   Neutral      9
# … with 18 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I thought this would solve a larger problem but unfortunately it didn't. If you have a chance please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838910/how-to-lock-colors-for-missing-categories-and-include-missing-x-axis-values-in

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more option using `expand`:

```
library(tidyverse)
count_data <- data %>% 
    count(Month, Outcome)  
    
count_data %>% 
    expand(Month, Outcome) %>% 
    left_join(count_data) %>% 
    replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

```
   Month Outcome      n
   <chr> <chr>    <int>
 1 Apr   Negative    48
 2 Apr   Neutral     12
 3 Apr   Pending      1
 4 Apr   Positive    75
 5 Feb   Negative    37
 6 Feb   Neutral      6
 7 Feb   Pending      0
 8 Feb   Positive    48
 9 Jan   Negative    49
10 Jan   Neutral      9
# ... with 18 more rows
```