# How to "lock" colors for missing categories and include missing x-axis values in stacked bar chart using a reactive dataframe ? R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a little web app that I built using flex dashboard and shiny.

This is the output I have. I have 4 outcomes that I color coded.

[image]

The problem is that when I select my inputs - not all of the inputs have the 4 outcomes so the plot sometimes doesn't plot the correct colors I want. For example in the graph above I have the outcome "Pending" as grey. In the graph below - there are two problems. The first being "Pending" outcome being orange and the months April and May missing.

[image]

I've tried a couple of different things and cannot solve this. My desired output would be to have every outcomes be "locked" to the color code I set. Positive = Green , Neutral = orange, Negative = red, Pending = grey. And if I could get the month to show for every input (even if its 0) that would also be great.

Here is my reproducible code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(readr)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(zoo)

#load data here
data <- read_csv("dta.csv")
```

Inputs {.sidebar data-width=300}
=====================================

**Begin by selecting a Continent and/or Nation Name.** Once selected - the table and analytics portion of the report will generate.

```{r}

selectInput("input_type","Select Continent Name: ", c("All", data$Continent))


```

You can also specify a project if needed.

```{r}
selectInput("input_type2", "Select Nation Name: ", c("All", data$Nation))

```

# page 1

### Stacked Bar Chart

```{r}


data <- structure(list(Continent = c("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"North America", "North America", "North America", "North America", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe"), Nation = c("United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", 
"Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", 
"Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", 
"Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", 
"Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
"Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
"Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Poland", 
"Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland"), Month = c("Jun", "Mar", 
"Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jan", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Jul", "Mar", "Jun", "Jan", "Jul", "Jan", "Jul", 
"Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "May", "May", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
"May", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jan", 
"Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Feb", "Apr", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "May", "Jun", 
"Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "May", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Mar", "May", "Apr", "Apr", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Apr", 
"Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "May", "May", "Jun", "Apr", "May", "May", "Apr", "Apr", 
"Apr", "May", "May", "May", "May", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jun", "Jul", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", 
"Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Mar", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Jan", 
"Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Mar", "Mar", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Feb", "Jan", "Feb", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Feb", 
"Feb", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
"Apr", "Mar", "Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Jan", 
"Apr", "Jan", "Jan", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar"
), Outcome = c("Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Pending", "Negative", "Pending", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Neutral", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Pending", "Positive", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Pending", "Neutral", "Pending", 
"Neutral", "Pending", "Pending", "Neutral", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Neutral", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Neutral", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", "Pending", 
"Pending", "Positive", "Neutral", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Pending", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Negative")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -335L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Continent = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Nation = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Month = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Outcome = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

data_react <- reactive({
  mc <- data
  if(input$input_type !="All")
    mc <- subset(mc, Continent == input$input_type)
  if(input$input_type2 !="All")
    mc <- subset(mc, Nation == input$input_type2)
  mc
})


renderPlotly(
  ggplotly(
ggplot(data_react() %>% 
              group_by(Month, Outcome) %>% tally() 
         , 
       aes(x = factor(Month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")), 
           y = n, 
           fill = factor(Outcome, levels = c( "Positive", "Neutral", "Negative","Pending")))) +
  labs(x="",y="Referrals") + labs(fill='Outcomes') +

  geom_bar(stat = "identity" ) + 

  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "#59a14f" ,"#f28e2b", "#e15759","#99918e")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size=14) 
  ,tooltip= c("n") 
  )
)   



```
````

Comment: Can you please check that it's reproducible and adjust it to make it so?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Updated to do aggregation and complete() step upstream, so that every Nation gets a full set of Month-Outcomes.

```
data_react <- reactive({
  mc <- data %>% 
    count(Continent, Nation, Month, Outcome) %>%
    complete(Continent, Nation, Month, Outcome, fill = list(n = 0))

...


renderPlotly(
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(data_react() %>%
         count(Month, Outcome, wt = n),   # consolidate for all Nations
                                          # currently selected
...
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, is there any way to keep all the month? For example April and May are still missing from Nigeria.

Comment: Hmm, I tried `complete(Month = unique(data$Month), 
                  Outcome = unique(data$Outcome), 
                  fill = list(n = 0)), ` but that seemed to copy the data in a way I didn't expect. Anyone else?

Comment: Updated, should work better. It should show every month present in the data set for every Nation / Continent.

Comment: Hey Jon, thank you for the help - is there anyway to force months missing from the data set to also appear? For example - is there a way to get August-December to appear even if they are null/0? Best

Comment: Sure, inside the `complete()` call, replace `Month` with `Month =  [the vector of months you want to be included for every entry]`.